# SSL self signed certificate not working on ipad / iphone

Tags: ios, windows, iis-7, ssl-certificate

We use IIS 7 and self signed certificates for our internal sites. All works perfect on windows PCs, laptops and from the server itself. the request https:// server/folder resolves correctly.

However, when we try to connect using an ipad or iphone, the page cannot be displayed. Chrome on iOS says "Page cannot be displayed" and Safari simply shows a blank page.

Is there any settings we need to change from the server side in order to make this work?